# Is there a Yahoo Finance ticker for NYMEX Crude Oil Front Month?

Tags: commodities, futures, yahoo-finance

I see tickers like on specific monthly futures like CLN13.NYM, CLQ13.NYM, etc. But is there on Yahoo Finance something like "CL1.NYM", i.e. ticker that always is pointing on the front month future. For example, there is such a thing on [FT site](http://markets.ft.com/research/Markets/Tearsheets/Summary?s=CL.1%3aNYM).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yahoo Finance doesn't offer this functionality; I remember looking for this exact feature a couple of years ago for coffee futures. Your best option is to look at the **[futures chain](http://finance.yahoo.com/q/fc?s=CLQ13.NYM+Futures+Chain)**. However, Yahoo Finance's future chains aren't always complete, since you'll notice that the futures chain for NYMEX crude oil omit the June contract. The contract [still exists](http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=CLM13.NYM&ql=1), but Yahoo doesn't list it in its own futures chain or in the [future chain for May](http://finance.yahoo.com/q/fc?s=CLK13.NYM+Futures+Chain).

Answer (score 2):

Yahoo Finance has this now, the ticker is [CL=F](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/CL=F).

Comment: Welcome, Ben. We don't do that here.